# What is the maximum disk capacity support for fdisk?

Tags: fdisk

What is the maximum disk capacity support for **fdisk**? Although we know we can't create partition larger than 2TB. Can we create three primary and 5 logical partitions out of 8TB disk?

Comment: Who says you can't create a partition larger than 2TB?  Why are you using fdisk instead of diskpart?

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft states that MBR has a hard limit of 2TB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2581408 . As you mention he should be using diskpart and GPT partitioning, but if he is on an old BIOS based system (rather than UEFI) then booting from a GPT disk is out of the question on Windows.

Comment: @Mokubai - I was using my comment to attempt to make the author use critical thinkink and in reaction get an edit that clarifies the question.  It's my understand that the 2TB with regards to MBR only applies to the system disk itself and doesn't apply to [secondary/trinary disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YAex.png).  I know I have several 3TB+ external disk which are MBR not GPT.

Comment: @Ramhound [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) claims that >2TB with MBR is possible if using larger sectors (since MBR entries hold numbers of sectors), but that can cause problems with legacy boot loaders.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - See Mokubai's comment for the rules that applies to the boot drive when it comes to MBR and Windows.  My comment applies to all other drives that are NOT the boot drive when it comes to Windows.  Please keep comments relevant to the author's question.

Answer (score 0):

None. `fdisk` "supports" whatever the disk's partition table ([Master boot record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) or [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)) supports - since all that it does is edit it.

---

Master Boot Record entries hold 32-bit unsigned values specifying each partition's *starting sector* and *number of sectors*.

So, you have at maximum `2**32-1` sectors of addressable space which is 2TB with 512B sectors and 16TB with 4K sectors.

Since the sum of two 32-bit integers can exceed 32-bit range, you can have a partition starting near the 2TB line and extending for another 2TB. Linux and Win7+ support this (see [Master_boot_record#Partition_table_entries @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Partition_table_entries)).

Extended Boot Records have the values count from the extended partition's start, but since an extended partition as a whole must have an entry in MBR, it doesn't enlarge the available space beyond what is possible in MBR.